# Problema ENOENT en Express.JS

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podéis ver en la imágen, estoy tratando de crear un servidor express.js pero no me deja debido a que me salta el error ENOENT, la verdad que no sé cuál es el problema debido a que no se lo veo por ningún lado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No veo la imagen. ¿Podrías agregar el código en formato texto? Incluyendo los mensajes de error. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: En el comentario anterior, @MauricioContreras te ha dicho que no se puede ver la imagen... **Y subiste otra imagen**. Lee [por qué es mala idea subir código y mensajes de error como imagen](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).

Comment: Además, ¿sabés a qué se refiere el error ENOENT? ¿Leíste el mensaje de error? Ese mensaje te da una ruta/dirección al archivo, ¿esa ruta existe?

Answer (score 0):

Tu `index.html`esta dentro de la ruta `public/css/js`, debes de moverlo y ponerlo en `public/index.html`